# WNetUseConnection returns ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT when called with host name

Tags: remote-access

I have the following code which only works when nr.lpRemoteName server part is specified with IP address.

When it's host name ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT will be returned.

I can access the file using host name from the machine that this code runs in.

Any ideas?

```
[DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
    IntPtr hwndOwner,
    NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
    string lpPassword,
    string lpUserID,
    int dwFlags,
    string lpAccessName,
    string lpBufferSize,
    string lpResult
    );

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private class NETRESOURCE
{
    public int dwScope = 0;
    public int dwType = 0;
    public int dwDisplayType = 0;
    public int dwUsage = 0;
    public string lpLocalName = "";
    public string lpRemoteName = "";
    public string lpComment = "";
    public string lpProvider = "";
}
    string password = "12345";
    string username = "ole1";
    const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001;

    NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    nr.lpRemoteName = @"\\[IP Address]\vids";

    //nr.lpRemoteName = @"[Host Name]\vids";


    int ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I suppose in the machine running your codes there must have another connection/session established using the host name and one user account other than <b>ole1</b>. You can verify this
1. Use Windows explorer to access \\Host Name\vids
2. Logon to the file share server, and open a command prompt with admin mode, and enter <b>net session /list</b> to see there is another session 
3. Even if you don't see any, there is a possibility that there exists some session/connection leak. You can call 
WNetCancelConnection2 to close any connection if there is

Answer (score 1):

It means your Windows login session already has a connection to that host, except that connection passed a different value in the [username] parameter.

> 1219 (0x4C3)
>
> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

Possible solutions:

- drop the old connection and make a new one, or
- pass the old connection's same value in [username], or
- start a new login session and make its own set of network connections, probably through Impersonation.